# Merge PHP Array's by values highest

Tags: php, arrays

I have these three sub arrays, I would like to make one array that 
searches through each array for the highest value, and puts its key 
into another array, to create a new array of key/key values

**Edit**
I'm looking through all 0's, then all 1's, then all 2's to find the highest value there. I want to always start with whatever the all time highest number is though, and move on to the smallest as the keys become unavailabl

**Input would be this**

```
Array
(
    Array
    (
        [0] => 16 
        [1] => 27 
        [2] => 36 // highest, 2 is now unavailable
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => 27
        [1] => 13.5  // highest, 1 is now unavailable
        [2] => 9 
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => 81 // highest, 0 is now unavailable
        [1] => 18
        [2] => 27 
    )
)
```

**Output would be this**

```
Array
(
    [0] => [2]
    [1] => [1]
    [2] => [0]
)
```

Comment: 26? I'm looking through all 0's, then all 1's, then all 2's to find the highest value there. I want to always start with whatever the all time highest number is though, and move on to the smallest as the keys become unavailable

Comment: Sorry I garbled the code. Okay so 81 is the all time highest number, so I take the key from it which is [0] and the key from the array that contains it which is [2]. I move on to the next highest number which is 36. I take the key from it which is [2] then the key from its parent which is [0] and move on.One of my BIG issues is that there might not always be the same number of arrays versus sub arrays. There might be four sub arrays and only parent arrays, or visa versa. In which case I just want to fill in as much as I can before there is not enough of the other.

Comment: Can we assume all sub arrays will always be the same length ?

Comment: Why not produce some code for yourself and tell us why it is wrong?

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder The sub arrays will always be the same length, but there might be more or less of them than the parents.

Comment: @ Ed I tried but it's just garbled as hell and would probably confuse you guys more than it would help. There is a lot more going on outside of this, but this is the root of the problem.

Comment: Do you want to check the arrays in order `[0][0], [0][1], [0][2]` or `[0][0], [1][0], [2][0]`? I still can't see the logic in what you posted, can you explain in more detail? In what order do the keys become unavailable?

Comment: Dude, don't take this too harshly... but, you really need to work on distilling and understanding your problems before touching any code. This also is a data structure problem (like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7249016/anyway-to-simplify-this-rats-nest-of-foreach-loops).

Comment: @deceze they become unavailable as soon as their value is considered the highest value left.

Comment: Not "when", *in what order*. Can I read your example in order? First 2 becomes unavailable, then 1, then 0? If so, I don't understand why 13.5 is higher than 27.

Comment: It's going by the highest numbers first 81 36 13.5, the 13.5 was the last highest number with an available key

Comment: That doesn't make any sense either, since the keys becoming unavailable will always be in the order 0, 1, 2... That's fine, but that means your example is incorrect either way. The answer you accepted doesn't use that algorithm either.

Comment: Many questions come to mind, a few of which are, what if there are identical values for the same index in two of the sub arrays? What if the all time highest value is not in the array index 0 ?

Comment: @Intersteller If there are identical values I use some I use another value from higher up as a deciding factor. I'm not sure how to explain it better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along these lines should do it, if I'm getting you right:

```
$result = array();

foreach ($array as $numbers) {
    $highestKey = null;
    $highestNum = null;

    foreach ($numbers as $key => $value) {
        if ($value > $highestNum && !in_array($key, $result)) {
            list($highestKey, $highestNum) = array($key, $value);
        }
    }

    $result[] = $highestKey;
}
```

Comment: @imoda I think you have missed the "key becomes unavailable" rule.

Comment: deceze, the code produced unexpected data. you can see the code here http://pastebin.com/J1zeW360, and the result here http://pastebin.com/HLGcnnSG

Comment: @deceze I'm sorry I'm really trying to explain this better than my work explained it to me. I agree that it makes little sense. It was explained to me that I am looking through each sub array for the all time highest number. I take the key that holds that number and save it, then look for the next, etc. I take the top most parent arrays key and associate it to the key that I saved. So each time I run across the highest number that's left, I pretty much delete it, take its key and associate it with the parent. Does that make any sense?

Comment: I'm sorry, I have a week left to do this class and I'm not an OO programmer. I'm ready to call them back and say it's impossible...

Comment: @ehime It would certainly be a good idea to work this out with pen and paper first and make yourself understand what you're trying to do. If necessary, confirm with your client.

Answer (score 0):

```
$results = array();
foreach ($array as $value) {
    arsort($value);
    $temp = array();        
    foreach ($value as $subkey => $subval) {
        if (!in_array($subkey, $results))
        $temp[] = $subkey;
    }       
    $results[] = $temp[0];
}
```

http://codepad.org/PAVHni6k